Huggingface pipeline available models
I'm working with Huggingface in Python to make inference with specific LLM text generation models. So far I used pipelines like this to initialize the model, and then insert input from a user and retrieve the response:
import torch
from transformers import pipeline
print(torch.cuda.is_available())

generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2', device="cuda")
#Inference code

However, when I change gpt2 with google/gemma-2b-it or some other models, it might ask for authentication or directly it thwors an error indicating it´s not available from pipeline().
I know some models need specific tokenizers and dependencies, but, is there any way to list all available models from pipeline()? And is there any way I can use other models inside pipeline() with all its dependencies without needing to import or use them inside the script?

Each error might need to be dealt with differently. Let's talk about the authentication issue that you mentioned.
For available models that you can use, check out their Model Hub (more information see The Hugging Face Hub Guide). You can use any tag to filter down to the specific task you are working on.
So most public models can be used by your pipeline() function, but some require extra step to access it (i.e. accept their community license for example).
To avoid authentication error in the future, your need:

Create access token (with read access)

Accept model term of use:
To accept it, go to the model page, in your case, it would be https://huggingface.co/google/gemma-2b-it to accept the term.

Log in to huggingface in your code by:


from huggingface_hub import login
login()

# or in notebook you would need
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()


Add access token to your function

import torch
from transformers import pipeline
print(torch.cuda.is_available())

generator = pipeline("text-generation", model="google/gemma-2b-it", device="cuda", token="your_token")


Every model with "token-classification" tag should be usable with pipeline : https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=token-classification
